# Fetch data-value of specific elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

When creating a scheduler type system that allows the user to choose months, days, hours and minutes they wish for task to run, I have created DIVs that represent each option. I used "data-value" to store the actual integer value that is the representation.

When they submit the form, I need to collect this information to place into arrays and pass to AJAX. I am however struggling to figure out how to do so. I need to basically get all months with the class "selected", all hours with the class "selected" and so on. Can anyone shed light on how I could do so?

I imagine there is some way to check each element within the DIV container but I am not sure how to do so.

```
var monthsContainer = $("#schedMonthsContainer");
var daysContainer = $("#schedDaysContainer");

for (i = 0; i < MonthsOfYear.length; i++)
{
    var month = MonthsOfYear[i];
    var monthEl = $("<div>", { 'class': "timeSegment selected", 'data-value': i, text: month });
    monthsContainer.append(monthEl);
}

for (i = 0; i < DaysOfWeek.length; i++)
{
    var day = DaysOfWeek[i];
    var dayEl = $("<div>", { 'class': "timeSegment selected", 'data-value': i, text: day });
    daysContainer.append(dayEl);
}
```

HTML

```
                            <div class="twelveSegmentContainer">
                                <div id="schedMonthsContainer"></div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="sevenSegmentContainer">
                                <div id="schedDaysContainer"></div>
                            </div>
```

Comment: share sample html also

Comment: I added it but its basically just empty DIVs, the javascript is what populates them.

Comment: How are you submitting the form?

Comment: I haven't added that code yet but I will be using AJAX to send 4 arrays (months, days, hours, minutes) to a PHP Handler which will create the task using an API.

Comment: Really not enough shown to know how this form and UI works. Suggest you create a simplified demo in jsfiddle.net or other code sharing site. May not even need a form if you bind event handlers to a data array

Comment: I will try that. My question is basically something along the lines of if doing something like $('#schedMonthsContainer').find('.timeSegment'); how do I check if it also has the "selected" class and get the "data-value" if so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will find all elements which have *both* the `timeSegment` class as well as the `selected` class:

```
$('.timeSegment.selected')
```

So, using the above you can retrieve the values of the `data-value` attributes like this:

```
$('.timeSegment.selected').each(function(index) {
    console.log($(this).data('value'));
});
```

#### Update

Finding out which parent belongs to `$(this)` can be done using: `parent()` or you could use `find()` on a certain element.

**Option 1: Using `parent()`:**

```
$('.timeSegment.selected').each(function(index) {
    var parent = $(this).parent();
    console.log(parent.attr('id'));
    console.log($(this).data('value'));
});
```

The above will retrieve the `id` of the parent element, so that could be `schedMonthsContainer` or one of your other containers.

**Option 2: Using `find()` on a specific element:**

```
$('#schedMonthsContainer').find('.timeSegment.selected').each(function(index) {
    console.log($(this).data('value'));
});
```

The above will only retrieve the elements with both the `timeSegment` and `selected` classes within the months container.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was trying to figure out but couldn't quite get it. How can I either specify which DIV to search in this example or alternatively get the parent DIV that $(this) is assigned to? I need to figure out if its a month, day, hour or minute.

Comment: @BrettPowell I've updated my answer. Is this what you were looking for?